# Linked list consecutive nodes

Tags: c, list, linked-list

Is there a way to get 5 consecutive elements of a linked list? I want to calculate the sum of 3 consecutive elements and compare it to the sum of the next 2 elements.

I have tried to save the elements in array and then check the sum but I think I'm getting apart from the problem

```
for(i=0; i<size;i++)
{ 
  array[i]=curr_item->type;
  curr_item=curr_item->next;
}

for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
  sum=(array[i]+array[i+1]+array[i+2]) - (array[i+3]+array[i+4]);
  if (sum>0)
     printf("Successfull\n")
  else 
     printf("Wrong\n");
}
```

Comment: Of course it is. But this is not a good question for SO.

Comment: Sure there is a way. But what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To traverse a typical link list it goes something like this (C style):

```
typedef struct list{
    struct list next,
    int value
} list;

list * iterator = headOfList;

while(itertaor != NULL)
   iterator = iterator->next;
```

All you would need to do from here would be to add some if-then logic inside of the while loop to add together the correct ordered elements. For example, to add the first two elements (assuming the list has more than two elements)

```
int count = 0;
int sum = 0;

while(itertaor != NULL){
       if(count == 0 || count == 1)
           sum += iterator->value;
       iterator = iterator->next;
       count++;
}
```

If you are using something more user-friendly you would must likely be able to get away with something like this (pseudo_code):

```
  foreach( item in list )
         if ( item is 1st, 2nd, or 3rd)
            add to running sum
```